# Flutter: Internet Connection appears to be offline on IOS

Tags: ios, flutter, connection

i'm developing an app with Flutter and i've a problem with internet connectivity. Particularly, with the WIFI connection every work well, but when i turn off wifi and active the mobile connection 4G the app does not work and put out this errors:

```
Runner[1930:178958] Connection 1: encountered error(1:50)

Runner[1930:178953] Task <291B2B98-3FAE-47ED-BA1C-39F75580220C>.<1> HTTP load failed, 0/0 bytes (error code: -1009 [1:50])

Runner[1930:178960] Task <291B2B98-3FAE-47ED-BA1C-39F75580220C>.<1> finished with error [-1009] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1009 "The Internet connection appears to be offline." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=50, NSUnderlyingError=0x282f9c210 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1009 "(null)" UserInfo={_NSURLErrorNWPathKey=unsatisfied (Denied over cellular interface), interface: pdp_ip0, ipv4, dns, expensive, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=50, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <291B2B98-3FAE-47ED-BA1C-39F75580220C>.<1>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
  "LocalDataTask <291B2B98-3FAE-47ED-BA1C-39F75580220C>.<1>"
), NSLocalizedDescription=The Internet connection appears to be offline., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://graph.facebook.com/v13.0, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://graph.facebook.com/v13.0, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}
```

How to fix it?

Forgive me if I have not used the forum to its fullest, but I am a new user. :)

Thanks in advance to those who will help me!